# Hpricot encodings in ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, character-encoding, ruby-1.9

I have a rails3 application running on ruby 1.9 here, and Im having some pain making encodings work.

My task was to open a remote html page, and parse some information from it.
all my code and database are in UTF-8, im using the # code: UTF-8, mysql fix, and so on.

The page I open, is in charset ISO-8859-1, and when my parser find strage characters it complains its not a valid UTF-8 one.

I tryed to use .force_encoding("UTF-8") in all strings I've parsed, but it still.
When I try to convert the whole page, I get this:

```
a = open("someurl")
b = a.read.encode("UTF-8")
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xE9" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
    from (irb):7:in `encode'
    from (irb):7
    from /Users/tscolari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /Users/tscolari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/tscolari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

how could I fix this? it seems it already went wrong when he "converted" the iso8859 page to ascii.

**UPDATE**

I tryed opening the url using 'r:iso-8859-1:utf-8', but apparently my problem now is with Hpricot, that I use for parsing.

```
>a = open(b, 'r:iso-8859-1:utf-8')
>a.read.encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
> Hpricot(a).inner_html.encoding
 => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

and all the errors again... probably this is an hpricot issue, but if anyone knows a fix, please.

Comment: Does it work any better if you use nokogiri instead of hpricot?

Comment: well, you can convert the inner_html to UTF-8 using force_encoding, but if you try using inner_text, force_encoding give you an error. The work around is to use either inner_html or inner_content instead of inner_text

Comment: I'll give nokogiri a try here! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hpricot - UTF-8 issues
invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)

```
require 'hpricot'
require 'open-uri'

doc = open('http://www.amazon.co.jp/') { |f| Hpricot(f.read) }

puts doc.to_html

open('http://www.amazon.co.jp/') { |f| Hpricot(f.read.encode("UTF-8")) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = open("someurl", "r:iso-8859-1:utf-8")
```

See [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697413/character-encoding-issue-in-rails-v3-ruby-1-9-2/4697471#4697471) for more details...