# Rails importing CSV fails due to mal-formation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I get a `CSV:MalFormedCSVError` when I try to import a file using the following code:

```
  def import_csv(filename, model)
    CSV.foreach(filename, :headers => true) do |row|
      item = {}
      row.to_hash.each_pair do |k,v|
          item.merge!({k.downcase => v})
      end
        model.create!(item)
    end
  end
```

The csv files are HUGE, so is there a way I can just log the bad formatted lines and **CONTINUE EXECUTION** with the remainder of the csv file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try handling the file reading yourself and let CSV work on one line at a time. Something like this:

```
File.foreach(filename) do |line|
  begin
    CSV.parse(line) do |row|
      # Do something with row...
    end
  rescue CSV::MalformedCSVError => e
    # complain about line
  end
end
```

You'd have to do something with the header line yourself of course. Also, this won't work if you have embedded newlines in your CSV.

Comment: I can't speak authoritatively, but my understanding is that this approach can backfire in cases where a field contains `\n`, since `File` will treat that as the start of a new line, whereas the built in CSV library knows how to handle that appropriately. Maybe somebody else can speak to this...

Comment: @toasterlovin Right, that can be a problem. However, in this case, you can't let `CSV` do the work because the CSV file in question has some malformed records and it seems that the semi-broken CSV file is keeping `CSV.foreach` from working.

Comment: I was playing around with this tonight, alternative approach forthcoming.

Answer (score 2):

One problem with using `File` to manually go through each line in the file is that CSV files can contain fields with `\n` (newline character) in them. `File` will take that to indicate a newline and you will end up trying to parse a partial row.

Here is an another approach that might work for you:

```
@csv = CSV.new('path/to/file.csv')

loop do
  begin
    row = @csv.shift
    break unless row
    # do stuff
  rescue CSV::MalformedCSVError => error
    # handle the error
    next
  end
end
```

The main downside that I see with this approach is that you don't have access to the CSV row string when handling the error, just the `CSV::MalformedCSVError` itself.

Comment: this one will load the whole file into the memory right?, any alternative that have same behavior as foreach?

Comment: @buncis It's been a while, but from what I recall, the `shift` method is what the CSV library uses under the hood to read individual rows from the CSV file for _both_ the methods that _do_ load the entire file into memory as well as the methods that _do not_ read the entire file into memory, so this should also avoid loading the whole file into memory unless you save references to the `row` variable in whatever you do in the loop.

Comment: yeah it was confirmed here https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-shift 

`btw why I cannot tag people?`