# Rails, Heroku and invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, heroku, redis

I have a queue of text messages in Redis. Let's say a message in redis is something like this:

```
"niño"
```

(spot the non standard character).

The rails app displays the queue of messages. When I test locally (Rails 3.2.2, Ruby 1.9.3) everything is fine, but on Heroku cedar (Rails 3.2.2, I believe there is ruby 1.9.2) I get the infamous error: `ActionView::Template::Error (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8)`

After reading and rereading all I could find online I am still stuck as to how to fix this.

Any help or point to the right direction is greatly appreciated!

edit:

I managed to find a solution. I ended up using Iconv:

```
string = Iconv.iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', message)[0]
```

None of the suggested answers i found around seem to work in my case.

Comment: i installed through heroku labs ruby 1.9.3, but i still get the same error :|

Comment: When requiring Iconv in Ruby 1.9.3 you get this warning: `iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.` The equivalent to your solution would be something like: `string.force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: Or `string = message.encode('utf-8', 'iso-8859-1')` might be better.

Comment: good point, thanks!.. the only thing that bugs me is that with my solution, now on my local machine (macosx) i see the converted one as "niÃ±o", whereas the not converted one are correct "niño". Still can't figure out why.

Comment: Ruby 1.9+'s default internal encoding is set to the same encoding that your computer is set to use. Heroku is using UTF-8. If your computer is set to something other than UTF-8 (i.e. ISO-8859-1) this would explain the difference in behavior.

Comment: Are you using UTF-8 to transfer data over HTTP? If not, have you configured Rails to use whatever encoding you're using over HTTP? By default, Rails uses UTF-8. Also, if you're not using UTF-8 you will want to make sure that you configure service connections to use or convert data to the proper encoding (and ensure their libraries are compatible).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697413/character-encoding-issue-in-rails-v3-ruby-1-9-2/4697471#4697471

Comment: Where do you put the `string = Iconv.iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', message)[0]` statement?

Comment: i was encoding email messages that were sent to my application. so this line was used before i put the text into redis. I just checked the code again (as it has changed since my original question) and now i am doing it like this:

- i first check what encoding the email is in
`email_text_encoding = JSON.parse(params['charsets'])['text']`

- i then use that encoding to convert it to utf8
`utf_ed = text.encode('utf-8', email_text_encoding)`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

On Heroku, when your app receives the message "niño" from Redis, it is actually getting the four bytes:

```
 0x6e 0x69 0xf1 0x6f
```

which, when interpreted as [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) correspond to the characters `n`, `i`, `ñ` and `o`.

However, your Rails app assumes that these bytes should be interpreted as [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8), and at some point it tries to decode them this way. The third byte in this sequence, 0xf1 looks like this:

```
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
```

If you compare this to the [table on the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8#Description), you can see this byte is the leading byte of a four byte character (it matches the pattern `11110xxx`), and as such should be followed by three more continuation bytes that all match the pattern `10xxxxxx`. It's not, instead the next byte is 0x6f (`01101111`), and so this is invalid utf-8 byte sequence and you get the error you see.

Using:

```
string = message.encode('utf-8', 'iso-8859-1')
```

(or the `Iconv` equivalent) tells Ruby to read `message` as ISO-8859-1 encoded, and then to create the equivalent string in UTF-8 encoding, which you can then use without problems. (An alternative could be to use [`force_encoding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-force_encoding) to tell Ruby the correct encoding of the string, but that will likely cause problems later when you try to mix UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 strings).

In UTF-8, the string "niño" corresponds to the bytes:

```
0x6e 0x69 0xc3 0xb1 0x6f
```

Note that the first, second and last bytes are the same. The `ñ` character is encoded as the two bytes `0xc3 0xb1`. If you write these out in binary and compare to the table in the Wikipedia again article you'll see they encode 0xf1, which is the ISO-8859-1 encoding of `ñ` (since the first 256 unicode codepoints match ISO-8859-1).

If you take these five bytes and treat them as being ISO-8859-1, then they correspond to the string

```
niÃ±o
```

Looking at the [ISO-8859-1 codepage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), 0xc3 maps to `Â`, and 0xb1 maps to `±`.

So what's happening on your local machine is that your app is receiving the five bytes `0x6e 0x69 0xc3 0xb1 0x6f` from Redis, which is the UTF-8 representation of "niño". On Heroku it's receiving the four bytes `0x6e 0x69 0xf1 0x6f`, which is the ISO-8859-1 representation.

The real fix to your problem will be to make sure the strings being put into Redis are all already UTF-8 (or at least all the same encoding). I haven't used Redis, but from what I can tell from a brief Google, it doesn't concern itself with string encodings but simply gives back whatever bytes it's been given. You should look at whatever process is putting the data into Redis, and ensure that it handles the encoding properly.