# Ruby CSV UTF8 encoding error while reading

Tags: ruby, csv

This is what I was doing:

```
csv = CSV.open(file_name, "r")
```

I used this for testing:

```
line = csv.shift
while not line.nil?
  puts line
  line = csv.shift
end
```

And I ran into this:

```
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

I read the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697471/724516) and this is what I tried

```
csv = CSV.open(file_name, "r", encoding: "windows-1251:utf-8")
```

I ran into the following error:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x98" to UTF-8 in conversion from Windows-1251 to UTF-8
```

Then I came across a Ruby gem - charlock_holmes. I figured I'd try using it to find the source encoding.

```
CharlockHolmes::EncodingDetector.detect(File.read(file_name))
=> {:type=>:text, :encoding=>"windows-1252", :confidence=>37, :language=>"fr"}
```

So I did this:

```
csv = CSV.open(file_name, "r", encoding: "windows-1252:utf-8")
```

And still got this:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x8F" to UTF-8 in conversion from Windows-1252 to UTF-8
```

Comment: Seems like [this][1] might work. ----


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9361667/724516

Comment: Could you upload your csv file ?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have problem with detecting the valid encoding of your file. *CharlockHolmes* provide you with useful tip of `:confidence=>37` which simply means the detected encoding may not be the right one.

Basing on error messages and `test_transcode.rb` from https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby/blob/master/test-mri/test/ruby/test_transcode.rb I found the encoding that passes through both of your error messages. With help of `String#encode` it's easy to test:

```
"\x8F\x98".encode("UTF-8","cp1256") # => "ڈک"
```

Your issue looks like strictly related to the file and not to ruby.

In case we are not sure which encoding to use and can agree to loose some character we can use `:invalid` and `:undef` params for `String#encode`, in this case:

```
"\x8F\x98".encode("UTF-8", "CP1250",:invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace, :replace => "?") # => "Ź?"
```

other way is to use `Iconv` `*//IGNORE` option for target encoding:

```
Iconv.iconv("UTF-8//IGNORE","CP1250", "\x8F\x98")
```

As a source encoding suggestion of *CharlockHolmes* should be pretty good.

PS. `String.encode` was introduced in ruby 1.9. With ruby 1.8 you can use `Iconv`

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm quite certain the issue is related to my file. I still need to be able to parse it though. I'm okay with losing some of the characters. Any idea?

Comment: ooh nice! this looks really useful. I'll give it a shot. Appreciate your efforts!