# CSV encoding error: "\x98" to UTF-8 in conversion from Windows-1251 to UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, utf-8

Got this error with CSV while using:

```
@csv = CSV.read(params[:file].path, headers: true, skip_blanks: true, encoding:'windows-1251:utf-8')
...
```

Error:

```
=> Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\x98" to UTF-8 in conversion from Windows-1251 to UTF-8):
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: you might find something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822380/ruby-csv-utf8-encoding-error-while-reading

Comment: How can I include that in my CSV.read?

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697413/character-encoding-issue-in-rails-v3-ruby-1-9-2/9361667#9361667

Comment: Only problem with that is its a csv so some lines are pure english and there is a line or two that are in different language (i believe arabic)

Comment: `\x98` isn't a character in [Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) so you're probably using the wrong encoding here. If it's Arabic, you might be looking for [Windows-1256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256).

Comment: Can I do 1251 and 1256?